# How error handling is done in Jcuda?

Tags: cuda, jcuda

In CUDA we can get to know about errors simply by checking return type of functions such as cudaMemcpy(), cudaMalloc() etc. which is cudaError_t with cudaSuccess. Is there any method available in JCuda to check error for functions such as cuMemcpyHtoD(), cuMemAlloc(), cuLaunchKernel() etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the methods of [JCuda](http://jcuda.org/) (should) behave exactly like the corresponding CUDA functions: They return an error code in form of an `int`. These error codes are also defined in...

- the [cudaError](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/runtime/cudaError.html) class for the Runtime API
- the [CUresult](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/driver/CUresult.html) class for the Driver API
- the [cublasStatus](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/jcublas/doc/jcuda/jcublas/cublasStatus.html) class for JCublas
- the [cufftResult](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/jcufft/doc/jcuda/jcufft/cufftResult.html) class for JCufft
- the [curandStatus](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/jcurand/doc/jcuda/jcurand/curandStatus.html) class for JCurand
- the [cusparseStatus](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/jcusparse/doc/jcuda/jcusparse/cusparseStatus.html) class for JCusparse

and are the same error codes as in the respective CUDA library.

**All** these classes additionally have a static method called `stringFor(int)` - for example, [cudaError#stringFor(int)](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/runtime/cudaError.html#stringFor%28int%29) and [CUresult#stringFor(int)](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/driver/CUresult.html#stringFor%28int%29). These methods return a human-readable `String` representation of the error code.

So you *could* do manual error checks, for example, like this:

```
int error = someCudaFunction();
if (error != 0= {
    System.out.println("Error code "+error+": "+cudaError.stringFor(error));
}
```

which might print something like

```
Error code 10: cudaErrorInvalidDevice
```

### But...

...the error checks may be a hassle. You might have noticed in the CUDA samples that NVIDIA introduced some macros that simplify the error checks. And similarly, I added optional exception checks for JCuda: All the libraries offer a static method called `setExceptionsEnabled(boolean)`. When calling

```
JCudaDriver.setExceptionsEnabled(true);
```

then all subsequent method calls for the Driver API will automatically check the method return values, and throw a `CudaException` when there was any error.

(Note that this method exists separately for all libraries. E.g. the call would be `JCublas.setExceptionsEnabled(true)` when using JCublas)

The [samples](http://www.jcuda.org/samples/samples.html) usually enable exception checks right at the beginning of the `main` method. And I'd recommend to also do this, at least during the development phase. As soon as it is clear that the program does not contain any errors, one could disable the exceptions, but there's hardly a reason to do so: They conveniently offer clear information about which error occurred, whereas otherwise, the calls may fail silently.